# Correct way to implement a metronome in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, timer

I'm quite new in Xamarin and currently developping a music-related app. One of it's functionality is a metronome, having the bpm as an input. The metronome is set ON/OFF by the press of a single button, and it ticks with a sound using the SimpleAudioPlayer plugin.

Below is my implementation, but the feeling is off : there is some lag, which, well, is not ideal for a metronome.

```
        // OFF by default
        bool _MetronomeOn = false;
        async private void btnMetronome_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            _MetronomeOn = !_MetronomeOn;

            // While Metronome is On
            while (_MetronomeOn)
            {
                // Get the bpm from ui
                double bpm;
                if (!Double.TryParse(entryMetronome.Text, out bpm))
                    bpm = 90;

                double secInterval = 60 / bpm;
                var player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
                player.Load("metronome.mp3");

                if (_MetronomeOn)
                {
                    // NOTE : Added Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer nugget package 
                    player.Play();

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secInterval));
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not sure what causes this... I think it can be the while implementation, the plugin loading maybe being heavy on the ressource...

Any help would be appreciated :)

EDIT :
Thanks to Jason, my first step was to load the mp3 once and not during each loop. I tried at first to push the var player globally (outside any function) but VS 2022 didn't want me to and I was too much a newbie to find the correct type. But I did :) :

I set up the player globally and loaded the mp3 once in the OnAppearing() method :

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        // NOTE : Added Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer nugget package to the Android Solution
        // The sound itself is loaded (not played) in OnAppearing()
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.ISimpleAudioPlayer player;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // When the main view is launched and Shuffle Button animation
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            // Load the mp3. It must be in :
            // Android : Asset folder and build action is AndroidAsset
            // iOS :  Resource folder and build action is BundleResource
            player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            player.Load("metronome.mp3");
            ...
        }
        
        ...
    }
```

This had a better result. Next step is implementing the correct timer, I'm working on it.

Comment: use `System.Timers`, not `Task.Delay`

Comment: also, there is no need to call `player.Load()` **every time** you loop.  You're always playing the same file, just load it once

Comment: You will never want to loop in an event handler. And pretty much infinitely on top.

Comment: Also, if you want a metronome click that is halfway decent, you cannot delay for a fixed time and play a sound. That will introduce a shift / error.

Comment: To clarify, make a repeating timer. Thus the interval will be constant, regardless of how long the code takes to play the sound. As mentioned, load the sound once, before starting the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here is the full code, thanks to you all.
Here's what I changed :

- Loaded the mp3 just once by putting Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.ISimpleAudioPlayer player; as a global variable and setting its parameters and loading the mp3 in the OnAppearing() method
- Added a System.Timers.Timer to handled the timer correctly. I dropped the _MetronomeOn variable as the aTimer.Enabled property let me know if it was running or not. It now works like a charm. No more ugly whiles !

Thanks a bunch !

```
namespace TestMetro
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        // NOTE : Added Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer nugget package to the Android Solution
        // The sound itself is loaded (not played) in OnAppearing()
        Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.ISimpleAudioPlayer player;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            // Load the mp3. It must be in :
            // Android : Asset folder and build action is AndroidAsset
            // iOS :  Resource folder and build action is BundleResource
            player = Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer.CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.Current;
            player.Load("metronome.mp3");

            // Initiate the timer -- tick rate to be set below
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnMetronomeTick;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void OnMetronomeTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtBPM.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
            player.Play();
        }

        // REMOVED _MetronomeOn Var
        private void btnClick_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            // Get the bpm from ui
            double bpm;
            if (!Double.TryParse(txtBPM.Text, out bpm))
                bpm = 90;

            double secInterval = (60 * 1000 / bpm);
            aTimer.Interval = secInterval;
            if (aTimer.Enabled)
                aTimer.Stop();
            else
                aTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```